# How to make chrome pin tab and display title too?

Tags: google-chrome

When you pin a tab, you no longer see the numbered update counts (right) for things such as Gmail, Twitter, and other services that give you a live count on the browser bar of new things going on within the page since the last time you were active on that tab.

How to make chrome pin tab and display title too?

**Edit:**
`Close some tabs or uninstall extensions that take a lot of memory. If there's a specific tab you don't want discarded, right-click on the tab and pin it.`

I found this not work. When the memory is too low, it will reload, either. In the `chrome://discards/`,the pin tab is also on top which means it is most closet to be discarded! Why?
[image]

Comment: For clarification, what feature of tab pinning are you wanting to keep while still seeing the title? Chrome can launch multiple tabs on startup if you're just wanting your mail to always be available.

Comment: I'm uploading some important files. I must pin it to avoid chrome auto reload the important tab( high memory will make a tab reload on chrome). I want to see the uploading state now, e.g.  12 of 155 uploading. @int_541

Comment: @int_541 `Close some tabs or uninstall extensions that take a lot of memory. If there's a specific tab you don't want discarded, right-click on the tab and pin it.
`
I found this not work. When the memory is too low, it will reload, either. In the `chrome://discards/`,the pin tab is also on top which means it is most closest to be discarded! Why?

Comment: @fly931 If you want to prevent tabs from reloading when memory usage is high, go to chrome://flags and make sure Automatic tab discarding is set to 'Disabled'

Comment: All if these comments are pointless since they don't address the OP's actual question but rather harass him about why he's asking.

Comment: I would love to be have this functionality, too.  To pin a tab without losing its title.

Comment: Best option I’m aware of right now is to utilize the chrome tab groups. You can create a group called "Pinned", and then you can enable an experimental feature at `chrome://flags/#tab-groups-save` to enable saved tab groups. You then save the tab group, and then you can sort of treat this saved tab group as "pinned".  There should now be a bookmark looking item next to your normal bookmarks with the name of the saved group.  This doesn’t directly solve the original question but I found it to allow a similar functionality.

Comment: Sad that Google still hasn't addressed this almost 7 years later. It's almost as if they don't use their own products.. but this isn't Android so we know that's not the case.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1495104

Answer (score 2):

You are a bit out of luck. As of today, there doesn't seem to be a way to avoid that.

There are tools leveraging the pin functionality but that still removes whatever custom title you choose.

I would suggest using something like "Tab Modifier" and not pinning the tab but instead protecting it and applying your own name/icon. Hope this helps :/